# Simplify comparsion with array

Tags: java, arrays, comparison

I got this simple code and I want to simplify the comparsion with array in while loop

```
int[] numbers = new int[7];

    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {            
        int number = rand.nextInt(46);
        while(number == numbers[0] || number == numbers[1] || number == numbers[2] || number == numbers[3] ||
                number == numbers[4] || number == numbers[5] || number == numbers[6]) {
            number = rand.nextInt();
        }
        numbers[i] = number;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
```

I want to find a way to simplify this part:

```
while(number == numbers[0] || number == numbers[1] || number == numbers[2] || number == numbers[3] ||
                number == numbers[4] || number == numbers[5] || number == numbers[6])
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution to this would be to use Java 8 streams.
With streams it looks like this:

```
int[] numbers = new Random().ints(1, 46).distinct().limit(6).toArray();
```

Thanks Elliot, I failed to recognice that the number `0` would not be choosen as all ints are 0 at the beginning.

Comment: I think that should be `ints(1, 46)` - OP has guards against `0` (because that's what `numbers` is initially filled with).

Comment: Best answer IMHO. Still used to mapping these things out :)

Answer (score 4):

You ***could*** use a `IntStream` to test if any number from `numbers` doesn't match, and only increment when it does. Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7;) {
    final int number = rand.nextInt(46);
    if (IntStream.of(numbers).anyMatch(x -> x != number)) {
        numbers[i] = number;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your condition is complex just create a separate method which returns true or false, like that

```
public boolean isNumberInArray(int[] array, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

while(isNumberInArray(numbers, number)) {
```

Now code looks much better

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of an Array.

Please view the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<Integer,Integer> numbers = new HashMap<>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {            
            int number = rand.nextInt(46);
            while(numbers.containsKey(number)) {
                number = rand.nextInt(46);
            }
            // saving the index with the random value - to be used for sorting, etc...
            numbers.put(number,i);
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

And the output (Note that the map-key is the random value and the map-value is the index):

```
{17=2, 19=3, 22=0, 40=6, 42=4, 44=1, 30=5}
```

[HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) also works quite well (as pointed out by [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn)):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {            
            int number = rand.nextInt(46);
            while(numbers.contains(number)) {
                number = rand.nextInt(46);
            }
            numbers.add(number);
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
[2, 35, 25, 10, 44, 30, 31]
```

Comment: I think you just hyper-complicated the solution. A `Map` with an integer key in such a way is almost no different than a linear collection.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ: Depends on what the user needs. After getting the Map you can remap it using the wonderful java-8 collections API, so that the indexes will be keys and the random values will be values. Did not add this to the solution since it is out of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about just simplifying comparison using loop then you can do:

```
int[] numbers = new int[7];

Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    int number;
    outer:
    while (true) {
        number = rand.nextInt(46);
        for (int n : numbers) {
            if (n == number)
                continue outer;
        }
        break;
    }
    numbers[i] = number;
}
for (int number : numbers) {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

But you should use Set or Streams as mentioned in other Answers listed here..